# how to use hDevMode from PRINTDLGA

Tags: c++, winapi

how to cast HGLOBAL to DEVMODE? I tried like this:

```
PRINTDLG pd;
pd.hDevMode = NULL;
if(PrintDlg(&pd)){
    DEVMODE* test=(DEVMODE*)pd.hDevMode;
```

Comment: *"I tried"* - That's not helpful. Vital pieces of information are: `1` What did you expect to happen? `2` What actually happened? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @I101I  Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`PRINTDLGA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-printdlga) documentation:

> `hDevMode`
>
> Type: `HGLOBAL`
>
> **A handle to a movable global memory object that contains a `DEVMODE` structure.**

So, use [`GlobalLock()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-globallock) to access the `DEVMODE`, eg:

```
PRINTDLG pd = {};
pd.lStructSize = sizeof(pd);
...

if (PrintDlg(&pd)){
    DEVMODE* test = (DEVMODE*) GlobalLock(pd.hDevMode);
    // use test as needed...
    GlobalUnlock(pd.hDevMode);
    GlobalFree(pd.hDevMode);
}
```